# Call child method from parent class python

Tags: python-3.x, class, parent-child

I have parent class which initiates a database session only

```
class SqlBackedApi():
def __init__(self):
    self.session = DBSession()
```

I have created 3 separate child classes for each table in database, one of which is

```
class DeviceHandler(SqlBackedApi):

    def addNewDevice(self, device):
        self.session.add(device)
        self.session.commit()

    def getDevice(self, *filterOperation, **whereParams):
        self.session ... bla bla 

    def updateDevice(self, device):
        self.session ... bla bla
```

I want to use all of these handler mothods by initiating single database session. which is possible be creating a `SqlBackedApi` object.

```
sql = SqlBackedApi()
```

but I cannot access the child class methods `updateDevice` , `addNewDevice` and `addUser`, `deleteUser` etc... 
Is it yet possible to do this in python ? or is my design approach wrong ? 
any suggestions for alternative/better approach ? 
thanks :)

using python3

Comment: If you want to use a single database session, and share it across other objects, , probably use a static variable to store it, that would be a singleton design pattern. When you create it in `__init__`, it's not singleton.

Comment: Isn't that what I am doing here, creating single variable `self.session` inside __init__ and sharing it across all child classes ?

Comment: Nope, the children will init their own session in each instance of `DeviceHandler`, inside the `__init__` method they inherited. Making `SqlBackedApi` a singleton would help, as mentioned, or using aggregation instead of inheritance.

Comment: Sorry but could you explain me with an example ? thanks